# Access Violation While Calling Form's Method

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a form TForm1 where I have kept cxSpreadsheet component on it. I have also created a class called TTest. TTest class contains two methods one for loading data and another for saving data.

When I am calling a method of TForm1 class inside TTest class method, even though the component is created it is giving an access violation when I call Test.LoadMyData method, it gives access violation to ATableView1 variable.

What wrong am I doing ?

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    dxSpreadSheet1: TdxSpreadSheet;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  public
    ATableView1 : TdxSpreadSheetTableView;
    procedure Initilize;
    procedure LoadData;
  end;

  TTest = class
  public
    procedure SaveMyData(MyValue : String);
    procedure LoadMyData;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Test: TTest;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1 := TForm1.Create(Self);
  Initilize;
  Test := TTest.Create;
  Test.LoadMyData;
end;

procedure TForm1.Initilize;
begin
  ATableView1 := dxSpreadSheet1.Sheets[0] as TdxSpreadSheetTableView;
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadData;
begin
  ATableView1.Cells[10,1].SetText('Test Application');
end;

procedure TTest.LoadMyData;
begin
  Form1.LoadData;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question you left out a very important piece of the puzzle. You've mentioned it in comments, but I repeat it here because it's the direct trigger of your problem. In comments you said the form is created as follows:

```
with TForm1.Create(Self) do
begin
  try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

Your problem is that within the call-chain of `ShowModal` you expect `Form1` to be assigned *specifically to the instance you've just created*. But clearly you haven't yet done anything to set `Form1`.

Your "solution" was to assign `Form1` within the `ShowModal` call-chain. While this solves your immediate problem, it is far from correct, and I'll explain why later. First I'll show the simple solution that would have avoided the problem altogether (note it's not a complete solution because there are far more problems with your code than you realise).

Solution, get rid of **with**:

```
//This first line is the most important.
//It explicitly sets which variable must be assigned to the new form.
Form1 := TForm1.Create(Self);
try
  Form1.ShowModal;
finally
  Form1.Free;
end;
```

Vishal, try it out. If you do, you'll see it works. And hopefully I have your full attention now. You didn't believe at first, but perhaps you now realise I really ***do** understand correctly*.

---

So why do I say your "solution" wrong? After all it seems to solve the problem....

> Well, you said it yourself: you expected `Form1` to be assigned at the start of `FormShow`. You're right, it should be. By assigning `Form1 := Self;` inside `FormShow` you're just patching up the earlier mistake. Surely you agree it's better to fix the original mistake than to just patch over it later?

But there's a deeper problem here... I'm not sure you understand the difference between "object instances" and "classes". (*If you do, then please still read the next few paragraphs for revision.*)

It seems you expected that when `TForm1` was created it should be automatically assigned to the `Form1` variable. It's as if you expected there would only ever be one `TForm1` in memory at any point in time. But `TForm1` is a class type; meaning it generally defines the behaviour for **any number of** object instances of the same type. Each time you create a `TForm1`, it's a new separate instance of the form. And each instance can have its own variable that is assigned to it. E.g.

```
JohnsForm1 := TForm1.Create(Self);
PaulsForm1 := TForm1.Create(Self);
```

Consider for a moment what happens with your incorrect "solution" if you needed 2 form variable? What would you write inside the `FormShow` method? `JohnsForm1 := Self;` ***or*** `PaulsForm1 := Self;`?

Of course you can still *choose* to keep only 1 instance of `TForm1` in memory at a time. But Delphi has no way to automatically know that is what you intend. So you should still do any desired assignments explicitly as above.

---

I mentioned there are still more serious problems with your code. It's related to the above discussion about object instance and class types.

Your `TTest` class makes a bunch of unnecessary assumptions:

- It assumes there will only ever be 1 instance of `TForm1`.
- It assumes the form will always be available when needed.
- And it assumes the form will be assigned to the `Form1` variable.

So again, if you need a `JohnsForm1` and a `PaulsForm1`, your code won't work.

A tiny change to `TTest.LoadMyData` and `TForm1.FormShow` solves these problems.

```
//Write LoadMyData so it can be told which form instance to load the data into
procedure TTest.LoadMyData(ALoadForm: TForm1);
begin
  ALoadForm.LoadData;
end;

//Change FormShow to tell Test which form to use in LoadMyData
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Initilize;
  Test := TTest.Create;
  Test.LoadMyData(Self);
end;
```

For the record, David already gave you this information in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31470395/224704). His answer also demonstrates the proper resource protection for the new `TTest` instance, whereas I've left it out for the sake of simplicity.

> By the way, these 2 little changes would have also solved your problem.
>   Basically, you had 2 mistakes in your code. The combination of both mistakes caused your problem.
>   You can fix either one to make the problem go away. But you should fix both to make your code better.

Comment: I highly appreciate your efforts towards making things working out gently. I do have 10+ years in purly in Delphi. I new the form creation should happen as you said: Form1 := TForm1.Create(Self);. I create the form that way only. But as I said the code is not written by me. I couldn't put entire stuff here because lot many time i restricted here to talk to the point. That is the reason I didn't mention so many thing here. Now please don't say that is my problem. The form creation which I mention is not done by me and it is used in entire application all the place and number is too high

Comment: I know that is completely wrong way, but the situation is I could not go all the places and change the code as we generally do. I completely agree with you as well as all of MASTERS who were putting comment here. But the saddest part is in spite of telling that code is not written by me ppl kept on sailing their thoughts unnecessarily. Anyway I don't care as usual. I am also a good learner that is the reason I wanted to learn something here. That's why I posted the issue here, how to get handle such situation when you come across in your entire huge project.

Comment: It's nothing about anybody who is right and who is wrong. For me it was just part of learning. And again, I highly appreciate your valuable efforts in clearing the doubts. If ppl remember, I wrote "how you would handle such situation?". There is one saying "You should not just read the NewsPaper, You should also read behind the News you are reading." I was expecting that but as I said you cannot write everything here. I agree I should mention at least complete point but there is a way to interact. I have accepted your efforts as an answer. Thank YOU So Much Craig. I appreciate Your Efforts.

Comment: @All: Please try to read beyond the sentences. (I am not saying you are God or imagine arbitrarily but try to see why someone has written that way. CONFIRM WHAT HE WANTS TO SAY. Then put your valuable solution towards it for healthy discussion). It would resolve lot many problems and assumptions towards others. Again, I would like to mention here. I was not against of any individual but just expecting that someone should try to understand what I wanted to say. Don't jump on proving that the code is wrong. Ppl already know before you the code is wrong. They want to know how to handle such code.

Comment: I would like to THANK everyone who "Tried" to convey their message but some how ppl failed to read beyond the sentences went wrong. Sometimes it is required to understand What is the intention and not what is written. No hard feelings from my side. Thanks All again for putting your efforts.

Comment: I'm pleased that you reconsidered and now understand and appreciate what we told you.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting in quite a muddle. Delphi methods operate on an implicit `Self` object, the instance. Also known as the target of the method call. If we write your code with the `Self` made explicit then it looks like this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1 := TForm1.Create(Self);
  Self.Initilize;
  Test := TTest.Create;
  Test.LoadMyData;
end;

procedure TForm1.Initilize;
begin
  Self.ATableView1 := Self.dxSpreadSheet1.Sheets[0] as TdxSpreadSheetTableView;
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadData;
begin
  Self.ATableView1.Cells[10,1].SetText('Test Application');
end;

procedure TTest.LoadMyData;
begin
  Form1.LoadData;
end;
```

As you can see you have a rather unholy mix of references to `Self` and to `Form1`. Note that the `Form1` global variable is instantiated in the .dpr file with this line of code:

```
Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
```

That leads eventually to `FormShow` being called on `Form1`. You then overwrite `Form1` and now there are two instances of `TForm1`. You call `Initilize` on `Self`, but then call `LoadData` on `Form1`.

The whole thing is a mess. The code might look like this:

```
// remove global variable Test

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  Test: TTest;
begin
  Initilize;
  Test := TTest.Create;
  try 
    Test.LoadMyData(Self);
  finally
    Test.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Initilize;
begin
  ATableView1 := dxSpreadSheet1.Sheets[0] as TdxSpreadSheetTableView;
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadData;
begin
  ATableView1.Cells[10,1].SetText('Test Application');
end;

procedure TTest.LoadMyData(Form: TForm1);
begin
  Form.LoadData;
end;
```

Instead of using global variables, we pass form reference as a parameter.

Once you get on top of this you might consider removing the global variable `Form1` completely. The IDE creates this variable under the assumption that each form will have exactly one instance. But there's no reason that should necessarily be so. Personally, I think that you will benefit in the long run by removing these global variables.

Answer (score 0):

As David so eloquently states, this is quite a muddle you've created. He's correct in stating that the IDE  inserts a line in the project file that automatically creates your forms for you. So creating it yourself is redundant.

The OnShow handler is probably the correct place to add some test data to the grid in this instance, but I wouldn't bother with the TTest class to do it. That is, get the logic working first, then move the stuff into another class if you want. I suggest this because it appears you don't have a very good grasp of how to do OOD. We were all there at one time! Simplify things first.

I did a video for CodeRage 9 that you might find interesting. It's called "Have You Embraced Your Inner Software Plumber Lately?" Search for it on YouTube. It'll give you some insight into this general topic (maybe too much).

Answer (score -10):

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    dxSpreadSheet1: TdxSpreadSheet;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  public
    ATableView1 : TdxSpreadSheetTableView;
    procedure Initilize;
    procedure LoadData;
  end;

  TTest = class
  public
    procedure SaveMyData(MyValue : String);
    procedure LoadMyData;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Test: TTest;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Form1 is nil, if I check before executing below statement.
  Form1 := Self; //This statement make my code work. mmmhhhhhaaaa Love This Statement.

  Initilize;
  Test := TTest.Create;
  Test.LoadMyData;
end;
```

Comment: This fixes the problem because the problem is exactly as I described. However, this is categorically a bad idea. Passing arguments via global variables is know to be very bad practice: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: Vishal, that is some of ugliest solutions I ever saw. Please take your time to fully understand what David is trying to tell you.

Comment: This is like saying: I don't know how to unlock my car with the key, but hey look, I managed to open it by smashing the window with a brick.

Comment: @Craig: That doesn't make any sense. Don't say anything whatever comes to your mind. If you understand correctly, I recently said that the form is creating directly and This Form1 is a variable is automatically declared the moment I created this form at design time. So the way form is created and in FormShow event atleast Form1 object should not be Nil then. I reapeat Again for you, since Form1 was nil, that's why I tried to create it. Now say for eample if I need to call any method of TForm1 class in TTest class method on some other button click event, then how do I call it ?

Comment: @Craig: I need an object by which I can call method of TForm1 class, Right ?

Comment: @LU RD: If somebody respect others then there is point in respecting them. For me too, I find this is the ugliest way of communicating by talking about others ability. I don't want to continue about that topic any more, since I don't value such ppl. There are better way to convey your message. And he is not something indigenous.

Comment: Tell me one thing, when I create a form using below code why Form1 is Nil ? If it is nil how to call TForm1's method on some other button click event if needed ? Code:==> with TForm1.Create(Self) do begin try ShowModal; finally Free; end; end;====> After this code the form TForm1 is created. Now Form1 is showing as Nil. Now, what's next stuff ?

Comment: @VishalTiwari: in the code is your comment, "with TForm1.Create[...] " you create an instance of TForm1, but that doesn't assign the result to your Form1 **variable**.  That's why Form1 is still Nil.  If you spent less time commenting about imagined slurs and more time taking the trouble to understand what people are saying, you would have fewer of these problems!

Comment: @ MartynA: Thanks for your advance suggestion. But if you little bit try to understand, I am not unnecessarily interested in wasting my words with such not useful comments. The code I shared what would you do, if you need to access TForm1's methods via TTest method ? Better you stop suggesting what should I do and what I should not. I think you are not understanding what I wrote in my lat post about my comments. Don't have so much of self-esteem.

Comment: Instead of giving non-productive suggestion, if you have any solution for below code when Form1 is nil, what would you do, if you tell that would be productive. I think nobody knows about this and just trying to beat around the bush by giving non-useful comments. This form creation code is not written by me, so just wanted to know. If you don't know atleast respect yourself and don't give any suggetion for your sake. Code:==> with TForm1.Create(Self) do begin try ShowModal; finally Free; end; end;====> After this code the form TForm1 is created. Now Form1 is showing as Nil. what's next stuff?

Comment: Simply reference to `Self` instead of `Form1` (as others have said). Why `Form1 == nil` is hard to say (`Application.CreateForm` isn't called and you've created your own instance of `TForm1` perhaps ?). Borland should never introduce those global variables (I'm deleting them personally, they are useless).

Comment: @VishalTiwari You have two problems here. First your coding skills are quite poor, and second you are dismissing solutions from people far more knowledgeable than you are. In order to improve your skills, first you have to admit to yourself that you are not the best programmer ever, and then start listening to what others are saying to you. Your solution is not proper solution, it works but you will never get better programmer if you just stick to what just works without understanding what is going on in code. Take David Heffernan's answer and learn from it.

Comment: @VishalTiwari Another thing you should keep in mind is that people here are trying to help you, not to put you off.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar:  Well said!  Let's hope you can get through where others have failed.

Comment: The design of this unit is incorrect. You can defend what you've done all you like, but that doesn't make it any better. Here's the fundamental flaw: the form cannot create itself, as you did initially. The global variable Form1 is initialized OUTSIDE the form when it's created by the project file. SECONDLY ... OnShow is NOT where you INITIALIZE the form! That should be done inside of OnCreate. OnShow is called every time a ShowModal occurs. Your code isn't calling ShowModal. It's not even calling Create, which is when OnCreate is called (once). Self and Form1 are referring to the same object!

Comment: "if you need to access TForm1's methods via TTest method" ... then you need to inject TForm1 into TTest somehow, like via constructor injection. The way you're doing it is completely wrong. It might work, but from an OOD/OOP standpoint, it's wrong. The whole approach is wrong anyway! But you're not listening to anything any of us have to say in that respect. Yes, it's entirely possible to get an improperly designed bunch of classes to work; so what? You have not explained the role of TTest, and nobody is sure what it's for. Absent that, all we can do is point out obvious flaws in the design.

Comment: @VishalTiwari Believe me, I understand what you did much better than you think. There was no need to try and explain. I understand why you had the problem in the first place. I understand how you came up with your "solution". I understand why your "solution" is **wrong**. And I know how to solve your problem _correctly_. I will post an answer explaining all this to you. In your comments, you've said you want productive and useful answers. If you're interested in learning, please read my answer carefully.